# Integration HDIV and restful APIs with Jersey

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey, hdiv

I have a Java Restful application that uses Jersey for the APIs implementation and that uses Spring for DI. I'm now trying to integrate HDIV for security.

However the official documentation has examples for the integration with Spring MVC, but not Restful Jersey applications.

Documentation here:
https://hdivsecurity.com/technical-documentation/doc.html

I read online that it's possible to integrate HDIV with REST, but I cannot exactly figure out how this is done, as I cannot find examples.

Does anyone know how this is done?

Answer (score 1):

As you said Hdiv can be integrated with REST APIs, particularly RESTFul APIs that implements the whole REST specification, including Hypermedia or HATEOAS level (level 3 within [Richarson model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html))

This REST support is included inside Hdiv Enterprise edition and that's why is not included in the link related to the technical documentation provided by you. The security level offered in that integration is exactly the same that we have been offering till now for server side MVC applications. It means that Hdiv can automate the protection against OWASP top 10 web risks in REST based applications .

Regarding JAX-RS support it can be possible if you are using the new hypermedia support included within JAX-RS 2/Java EE 7.

If you need more detail about the Hdiv support for RESTFul APIs you can review the [slides](http://es.slideshare.net/hdivframework/securing-restful-services-with-spring-hateoas-hdiv) presented in the last Spring I/O conference.

If you want to test within your project this support please contact using Hdiv support web form within hdivsecurity.com web site.

Regards,

Roberto Velasco